# Creating and querying questions/answers in Ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

We're creating a Ruby-on-rails application where the user is presented with a series of questions where they can give multiple different answers to one question. For now it's it's toggles but in the future we might be interested in doing freeform text as well. Each group of answers is connected to a pin on a map.

For now, each pin simply has a coplumn of questions and answers, which is a hash, but we'd really like to make it nicer and more scaleable. Some of the queries we'd like to do are e.g. count the amount of people that have answered *'It's quiet here'* to the question *'Why do you come here?'*

For now, I thought of the following models:

```rb
# pin.rb
class Pin < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :questions
end
```

```rb
# question.rb
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :pin
  has_many :answers
end
```

```rb
# answer.rb
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :questions
end
```

Is this the right way of approaching this? I'd then fill `seed.rb`with the questions and possible corresponding answers.

What's the best way of then creating new objects or rows, when a user answers a given question?

Comment: Seems fine; it's not clear what the issue is. You may want to associate a given answer with a user as well as the question.

Answer (score 1):

This looks good to me. If your `Answer` defines possible choices for a question, then for storing user answers/selections, you'll have to create another model/table

```rb
class UserAnswer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer

  # attribute :value
end
```